# ng build error for package node-forge during deployment

Tags: angular, node-forge

We are getting below error in our docker deployment
ng build fails due to URLSearchParams is not defined at Object. (/usr/src/app/node_modules/node-forge/lib/log.js:305:5)

Answer (score 1):

This error started coming today in our deployment servers but our local was working fine.
Issues is with node-forge latest version v1. We need to copy our package-lock.json file in docker to install stable 0.10.0 version and after that the build was successful.
Link to Github isssue - https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/issues/942